# How do I use deep-linking in android to open app and fetch arguments?

Tags: android, deep-linking

So I am trying to do a `deep-linking` in my application to confirm the email the user inputs. So far I am not being able to open my application throws the link the backend gives me.

So far I have done this.

**This is my manifest.xml**

```
 <activity
            android:name=".ui.registration.activities.ARegistration"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="something.com"
                    android:path="/verify-email" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**This is my URL in my email**

https://something.com/verify-email?registrationId=1111&token=12345

**This is my Register activity**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.a_registration)
        colorStatusBar(frameRegistration, R.color.colorPrimary)

        val data = intent?.data

        val token = data?.getQueryParameter("token") //trying to obtain the token here
        Toast.makeText(applicationContext,token,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

}
```

Can someone help?

Comment: are you sure that activity lunch correctly and just can't obtain arguments?

Comment: The app does not open, that is my first problem

Comment: does not open via opening link. I understood correctly?

Comment: yes, when I click on the link the browser opens up and thats it

Comment: Do you have any ideia of whats causing this @beigirad?

Comment: I'm testing your code. wait!

Comment: ok thanks for the help

Comment: Is it because it has https? :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<data
    android:host="something.com"
    android:pathPattern="/verify-email"
    android:scheme="https" />
```

paste this and you are fine.

or 
if this doesn't work then go to : Settings -> apps -> your app -> set as default. and change "go to supported URLs" to always ask or in this app. may be you selected browser as default for your app to open url link

Comment: I paste that, and I am not fine :)

Comment: I tested it and app opened up. you have to replace your data xml tag with this in manifest.

Comment: you are using path attribute. You should use pathPattern .

Comment: if this doesn't work then go to : Settings -> apps -> your app -> set as default. and change "go to supported URLs" to always ask or in this app. may be you selected browser as default for your app to open url link.

Comment: How can I change this to be like this by default?

Comment: it seems your code worked first time you chose browser and it was selected as default also. to always open your app for supported links choose "in this app" option and it will open all link in your app by default. But I prefer always ask option.  please accept answer if it solved you problem.

Comment: My question is, how can I do that programmatically?

Comment: Please refactor the question with your Settings -> apps -> your app answer and the programmatically way to do it and I will accept it

Comment: I never had to do that programmtically so I don't know but there should be a way to do that. Best of luck for that. BTW I refactored asnwer.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works correctly. [Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQSO4.png)

but for trigger your app, copy and paste url in browser does not affect. You should use a html with a link and tap it or use `App Links Assistant` that placed in `tools` menu in Android Studio [[link]](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing).

#### html file that hosts on a local server to simulate real scenario:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<a href="https://something.com/verify-email?registrationId=1111&token=12345">Lunch</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

#### App Links Assistant:

[image]

Comment: Ok first thanks for the help. Second I use a link that I tap to open my app. I use this link https://something.com/verify-email?registrationId=1111&token=12345

Comment: I used this link too! and did not change any code! but added this url in a html file and tapped link and take upper shot

Comment: Yes but I wanted to avoid app links because it requires the web team to change stuff on their side. Is there any other way using deep linking?

Comment: You can define any link with any scheme for lunching and passing arguments. can you explain your application deep-link scenario? what link do you want to lunch activity?

Comment: Yeah so, I have an email confirmation link, where after I clicked it, I should return to my application, specifically to the Registration Activity.

Comment: The problem is that, when I click the link in the browser , does not open my application.

Comment: I describe this problem before. for solving problem, test above html file!

Comment: copy/paste in chrome url input does not trigger any thing!

Comment: Could it be the emulator?

Comment: So I am not copy and pasting, I have a url in my email sent from the backend team, where I click

Comment: That's great. Yes I use MAMP to create a local web server. And after that open this html in chrome in my emulator. And tapped link. Do you test second method that I said?

Comment: Could it be that you are doing those intent filters in the MainActivity, becuse I tried everything except the creation of the server you told me, because this needs to work with the url tha they provide me